# Could I add flavored Cappuccino syrup?

Tags: extract

I have a raspberry flavor syrup, the ones used in cappuccinos, and I was wondering if I could add a little in the last minutes boiling. Anyone have experience with this sort of syrups? They have a god taste but a lot of corn syrup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using real raspberries?

I found a good recipe online... here is a quote and the link.

> I normally use about 3 lbs of fresh raspberries for a five gallon batch. You can buy them fresh in late summer just about anywhere but I like produce stores. They usually have the best prices and the freshest inventory. Grocery stores are usually higher priced. I like fresh but frozen will also work, if you miss the season. I've used more but as I keep piling up those six ounce containers, little dollar signs start spinning in my head. If you are in a place where they grow raspberries they might be cheaper. Black ones will give a more distinctive color but the flavor is about the same either way.

[Raspberry Ale](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f12/raspberry-ale-55316/)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to make the puree instead ruin my beer with random chemicals.

Answer (score 1):

I would be suspect of these. Check the ingredient list. Corn syrup is not so bad, but if there's a lot of preservatives or ANYTHING with dairy or oil, then I wouldnt use it.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look in the ingredients first.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add anything to the boil if you want to retain the maximum amount of flavor and aroma.  Add it post fermentation.

Comment: If I add it at bottling or second fermentation. I don't want to add it at bottling because I'm not sure about how much CO2 the syrup can generate.

Comment: The syrup has nutrition facts, doesn't it? You should be able to get a reasonable guess using the sugars listed there.

Comment: Ok, some random stuff in the syrup: Potassium sorbate, artificial colors, sodium benzoate ad citric acid... I don't think that a beer should have these friends.

Comment: I agree with you!